# Redirect To Login Page in asp.Net

Tags: asp.net

I have a strange issue of Redirecting to the login page when i run my site for the time.

Issue is:-

When i tried to logged In to my site with correct User-Credentials it works perfectly and i can able to see my dashboard without any error(than means the Session of the User is properly generated).
 
But, as soon as i link towards the other pages  in the site it redirects me to Log In page with the RedirectURL of that page (where i  have to again insert the user credential and go through the site after that no error occurs).

After Successful Logged In, I tried Log-Out and re-login than it works perfectly. 
Issue occurs only once when i run the site for the first time.

Please guide me and take me out from this strange issue.

Thanks 
Prashant

Comment: what kind of authentication are you using?

Comment: We have used simple Form Authentication. Nothing more complicated 
Its perfectly working in our Local Environment and Test server. But when we upload it to live it behaves as mentioned above.